# Run Tasker if battery falls from a specific value to another one?

Tags: tasker

I am struggling to set up a Tasker profile so that it performs a task when battery falls from value X to value Y.

I always get the error that the Y value (to) cannot be smaller than the X value (from).

Does anyone know how to properly set up a Tasker profile that runs a task when battery falls from a certain percentage to a lower one?

Comment: Do you really need to set the starting value? like X is 100% and y is 20% then there is no use of the start value. Just set trigger to "if battery percentage reaches X% && it is not plugged in charge"

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find this trigger?

Comment: @Aayush for me it would be if battery falls from 30% to 29%.

Comment: Do you really need to use Tasker?? Want to try any other app? Easier to use.. I will suggest you to use Automate app.. It is very easy to use and has various functions too..

Comment: Will give that one a try, thanks!